# Table of Contents Spacing

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

How do I place vertical spacing between the chapter header and the first section entry (report document class). For example, I would like:

> Chapter 1 Title
>
> 1.1 Title
>   1.2 Title
>
> Chapter 2 Title
>
> 1.1 Title
>   1.2 Title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use redefine `\cftchapafterpnum` from the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package to add vertical space after the chapter entries:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip15pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without using additional packages, a redefinition of the internal command `\@chapter` (implemented in `report.cls`) will do the job (see the line marked with `a%NEW`):

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}% NEW
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```